# Notification by email before the date expires in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

As I have little knowledge about programming, I come to ask for help from this community.

I have [this Google spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kj2D7toWwHwEa-5ztubK2REPmy6DEaD_l3fQ_Q-eaJ4). And I want to create a script, which sends me an email notification for example 1 day before a date in question.

For example:

[image: see image]

The deadlines are in column H, and when for example 1 day was missing for the date, which is in column H and line 8, I wanted to receive a notification by mail with the content that is in line 8, the idea would be this.

Comment: May we see any research you have, or any unfinished code that you have tried?

Comment: Hello, I do not have any code made, because I have no knowledge about programming, I searched in google for cases identical to mine, but I can not find identical information ... I only see tuturiais of how to send a simple email, but it is not quite that What do i want

Comment: Right, well you may get an answer below, but it's worth noting that we get many requests for free work on Stack Overflow every day, and we don't want to become known as a place where that happens - we would be completely inundated (we are already, really). If you are not a programmer yourself, you could approach a freelancer and get a couple of hours of their time. Perhaps have a look at sites like AirPair?

Comment: Okay, I understand, I thought it was simple to do. I already found a lot of programming here on this site, which helped me to learn some things, and to do some interesting things in raspberry pi. That's why I thought about asking for help.
Thank you
greetings

Comment: It might be simple, it might not - we get a lot of requests in the form of "this would be really easy for you experts so plz do it for me" and we have to put a stop to that. Our preferring some prior effort is the only good way to discourage people who have no intention of trying (not saying that applies in your case, but we get a lot of that as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script editor variation of following snipet will do what you want.

```
function notify()
{
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue() == CONDITION)
{
MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@yourdomain.com,", 
    "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
}
}
```

It just check a basic condition, feel free to change it to your needs.
As for the output email, you can change the 3rd parameter to anything you want.

EDIT: to check the day condition just do:

```
var var1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
var var2 = DATEDIF(var1, TODAY(),"D");
```

and change the if to:

```
if(var2 == 1)
```

Note I didn't try the script, there might be typos.

Im going to edit one last time to be more specific after that you have to do research on how to do a google sheet script.

1)

```
var var1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
```

this line will give the script the value of the cell it has been called in.
i.e. if you type in your cell "=nofity()" the "notify()" function will be called.

2)

```
var var2 = DATEDIF(var1, TODAY(),"D");
```

DATEDIF is a google sheet function that give you the number of Day("D") month ("M") or Years("Y") between two dates.
As var1 is the content of the cell you called notify from, it will give you the number of day between H8 and TODAY in days.

Then if var2 is one then you enter the if and send an email via:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@yourdomain.com,", "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
```

First parameter of sendEmail is the address, followed by the object and the text of the email.

Note2: script is missing some parts, its on purpose to make you think.
Your question is  a basic use of google scripts, if you have no idea how to use/do one, you should read some tutorials, there are lot of them and its -really- easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I said I do not understand much programming, if you could be more specific, I would appreciate it.

The idea is to search for the expiring dates in column H, and then receive mail notification of the entire line, where the expiring date is.

greetings

Comment: I shouldnt have answer your question , so consider it as my last edit. You need to read tutorials on script, this script is more than simple. Good luck on coding it, the version I provided will not work as it, but is really close to work as you expect.

Comment: One more clue: to make it work you need to add a parameter to notify() function, so notify can read the cell you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tips, I'll study the subject and develop the code, thank you